# How to add Ankh to 2 installed side-by-side versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I just started at a new company and inherited a PC. It came with VS 2013 installed and I just installed VS 2017 to run side-by-side (I'll need both). I then installed the latest version of Ankh but it only detected VS 2017 during the installation.

How do I add the Ankh plugin into VS 2015 after it has already been installed in VS 2017?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two current versions of AnkhSVN:

- [AnkhSVN for Visual Studio 2017 (AnkhSVN 2.7)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio)
- [AnkhSVN for Visual Studio 2015 and older versions (AnkhSVN 2.6)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio)

You have the version for VS2017 installed, but the other one is missing.

BTW, have you tried [VisualSVN plug-in](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/)?

Comment: Thanks, I realized that after I posted the question but forgot to loop back here to post it. I'm used to using Ankh and as I understand it, the VisualSVN plugin is only free if not connected to Active Directory.